# Use of external Struct in a Class and C++ performance status?

Tags: c++, performance, class, struct

I saw the code below in a sample project. I couldn't find a satisfactory answer on the contents of the books I had. I have a few questions about it.

> **What is the difference between being specified in the first_name and last_name variables in struct and identifying them with an external
> struct?**
>
> **If there were millions of records, which one would you prefer in terms of performance and should it be?**
>
> **Or are there friends to share information about C++ tricks and obligations?**

**Thank you so much to everyone who took the time and answered.**

```
struct Name
{
         string    first_name;    // Name
         string    last_name;     // Last Name
};


class CPerson
{
        protected:
                    Name m_name;                    // Struct
        public:
                    void                SetName(string n);
                    string          GetName(){  return(m_name.first_name+" "+m_name.last_name); }
        private:
                    string          GetFirstName(string full_name);
                    string          GetLastName(string full_name);
};
void CPerson::SetName(string n)
{
            m_name.first_name           =       GetFirstName(n);
            m_name.last_name            =       GetLastName(n);
}
string CPerson::GetFirstName(string full_name)
{
            int     pos                     =       StringFind(full_name," ");
            if(pos>0)       StringSetCharacter(full_name,pos,0);
            return(full_name);
}
string CPerson::GetLastName(string full_name)
{
            string  ret_string;
            int     pos                     =       StringFind(full_name," ");
            if(pos>0) ret_string=StringSubstr(full_name,pos+1);
                    else ret_string         =       full_name;
            return(ret_string);
}
```

Comment: There is no performance difference between using a variable of type `Name`, and using two separate `string` variables for first and last name. The struct here is purely for code organization reasons, not for any performance reasons. `CPerson` could be trivially modified to not use `Name`.

Comment: No performance difference at all. On the code posted there is one obvious performance issue though. You have a setter which splits the name into first and last name, but your getter just puts the two names back together again. Don't you think that's a waste of effort? Think about that kind of issue instead.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference, because using of this variable is resolved in compile time. It is upon to you if you use struct, if you use in some place both `first_name` and `last_name` it may be easier for you and more readable to use struct.